# vmwared shared folder not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 guest operating system running on a windows 10 host, I am using VMware workstation 15 player.  I have been trying to set up a shared folder but the shared folder doesn't seem to be showing up.

**The Problem**

My shared folder doesn't seem to be appearing under the default path /mnt/hgfs on Ubuntu. In fact /mnt/hgfs doesn't even exist only /mnt/ exist.

**What I tried**

After some digging around I discovered that running `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl` should fix my problem. Unfortunetly when I run `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl` I get `sudo: vmware-config-tools.pl: command not found`. I checked if `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop` is installed and it is with the latest version.
The next thing I did was to check if my Ubuntu guest was able to detect that there is a shared folder on my host OS by running `vmware-hgfsclient` and the name of my shared folder came up.
[Here's a screenshot of my terminal after running the "what I tried" commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buiXz.png)

Any idea on things I can do to access my shared folder in Ubuntu (my guest OS)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vmware workstation has a tool called VMware tools which allows you to share files between your vm and your host computer here is a reference to install on workstation 14

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-391BE4BF-89A9-4DC3-85E7-3D45F5124BC7.html

Try to install this before run the perl installer sudo apt-get install build-essential and sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r).

Execute the perl file with sudo perl vmware-config-tools.pl sometimes you need dependencies like headers or builtin tools.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Do not worry vmware workstation has a tool called vmware tools which allows you to share files between your vm and your host computer here is a reference to install https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html, execute the perl file with sudo perl vmware-config-tools.pl sometimes you need dependencies like headers or builtin tools.

Comment: Try to install this before run the perl installer sudo apt-get install build-essential and sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Holly your comment lead me to finding a solution.  The reference that you sent is for an outdated Workstation.  What I had to do was go under Player -> Manage -> Reinstall VMwareTools. After re-installing the tools, everything worked as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/849948)

Comment: @Mureinik What is the correct protocol here. The correct answer appears in the comment section of what was originally a lousy answer.  Should I be marking the lousy answer as correct or should I re-post the comment in a new answer?  I want to be able to give credit to Holly if possible.

Comment: @Nicolasome personally, I'd ask Holly to edit the answer so it includes the right details from the comments.

Comment: @HollyDoge Can you edit your answer to include the right details so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Ok, I will edit the comment thank you @Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

> Setting a shared folder in VMWare Workstation
>
> *Step 1:*

Power off your virtual machine

Right-click on the Virtual Machine -> Settings... or VM (menu) -> Settings...

Go to the `Options` tab -> Select `Shared Folders` -> `Add..`
(Folder sharing: `Always enabled`, and don't forget to put the checkmark on the `Host Path` box)

[image: img_Shared_folder]

> *Step 2:*

Power on your virtual machine

Open your terminal and type

```
cd /mnt
ls
```

You should see `hgfs` listed there, if you can't see `hgfs` then type

```
sudo mkdir hgfs
```

> *Step 3:*

Now type  the following commands

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove open-vm-tools

sudo apt purge open-vm-tools
```

then go to `VM (menu)` -> Click on `Reinstall VMware Tools...`

Now VMware tools mount on your Desktop

Select `VMwareTools.tar.gz` folder and extract it to the Desktop

Open `vmware-tools-distrib` folder -> Right-click on it and choose `Open in Terminal`

```
ls
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

(It would ask about different parameters, hit **Enter** key every time to accept)

> *Step 4:*

After finishing the installation go to `Filesystem -> mnt -> hgfs` (`/mnt/hgfs`) you can see your shared folder listed there

> *Step 5:*

Select your shared folder, hold **Ctrl+Shift** key and drag it to Desktop to create a shortcut of it.

Answer (score 0):

Mir Rahed Uddin's answer work for me!!!
Originally, my 「reinstall vm tool」 option was greyed out. But I followed the following command which was from Mir Rahed.

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove open-vm-tools
sudo apt purge open-vm-tools
```

The 「reinstall vm tool」 option was not greyed out anymore. It was turned to install vm tool option. So I click the option. Then, you will see ther is an vmware tool on your desktop. Now VMware tools mount on your Desktop

1. Select VMwareTools.tar.gz folder and extract it to the Desktop
2. Open vmware-tools-distrib folder -> Right-click on it and choose Open in Terminal
3. exe following command

   sudo ./vmware-install.pl

Now you can go to `/mnt/hgfs/{share-folder-name}`, and use `ls` command. You will find the folder you shared in host.